# How to achieve word completion (google search style) in MS Outlook and MS Word

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word, typing

When doing a google search, one can take advantage of word completion. E.g., when one searches for drug rosiglitazone, one can just type 'rosi' and it offers rosiglitazone.

When a user writes emails or essays with lot of technical terms (e.g., drug names) in Outlook/Word, how can one achieve similar word completion capability?

Answer (score 1):

Word provides auto-complete functionality through phrases added as Autotext entries. For further details have a read of [Autotext](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/word-help/add-autotext-HA010255209.aspx) on the Office help page.

Comment: Thx. Some limitations I found are AutoTex is stored in template. AUtotext for emails (EMAIL NORMAL TEMPLATE) is not shared in MS WORD. I wish there was a cross application solution like typing on Android touch keyboard. maybe Autohotkey solution....

Comment: migrating your Frazes from old 2003 to 2007 seems also a problem.